# Inserting a variable into a string in PHP

Tags: php, escaping

I'm putting html variable inside php var but they aren't escaped correctly so I have problem: who can help me? here here it is the code:

```
$var['foo'] = "<p>$coord->name</p><p>$coord->address</p><a href=\"<?php echo site_url('info_hospital/$id'); ?>\">Details</a>";
```

where it's the problem ?

Comment: This is not how it's done. See  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you know that that PHP block won't be executed in the string?

Comment: yes this bloc it's not exectued. So I think it isn't escaped correctly...

Comment: Why don't you try [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... several errors in there, but this should work:

```
<?php 
$var['foo'] = "<p>{$coord->name}</p><p>{$coord->address}</p><a href=\"" . site_url("info_hospital/$id") . "\">Details</a>";
```

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work...the href it isn't escaped correctly

Comment: Do you mean that the string returned by your `site_url()` function isn't escaped properly? If so that's an entirely different problem but should probably be solvable with `urlencode()`.

Comment: Well to help you with that we'd really need to see the inner workings of that function. Or you could try `urlencode()` like I said.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var['foo'] = "<p>".$coord->name."</p><p>".$coord->address."</p><a href=".site_url($id).">Details</a>";
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

For working with such large strings, I favor using [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$var['foo'] = sprintf(
  '<p>%s</p><p>%s</p><a href="%s">Details</a>', 
  $coord->name, 
  $coord->address, 
  site_url($id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation generally has a small performance advantage over double quotes.  Also, in text editors that highlight syntax, the variables stand out better.

```
$var['foo'] = '<p>' . $coord->name . '</p><p>' . $coord->address . '</p><a href="' . site_url('info_hospital/$id') . '">Details</a>';
```